# Prove the Hyberbolic identity

Tags: trigonometry

(Note: The ? is where I have to fill in something)

Prove:

$$
\begin{align}
\sinh2x & = 2\sinh x\cosh x\\
\sinh2x & = \sinh (x + ?)\\
& = \sinh x(?) + \cosh x \sinh x\\
& =\space?\\
\end{align}
$$

I know that there is a way of proving it by using the basic definitions of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, but that is not what the question is asking.

Comment: Hint: $2x=x+x$.

Comment: where did the hyperbolic cosign go?

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**
Recall that
$$\cosh(y) = \dfrac{\exp(y) + \exp(-y)}2$$
and
$$\sinh(y) = \dfrac{\exp(y) - \exp(-y)}2$$
Make us of the identity
$$(a^2 - b^2) = (a+b)(a-b)$$
Hence,
$$\sinh(2x) = \dfrac{\exp(2x) - \exp(-2x)}2 = \dfrac12 \left((\exp(x))^2 - (\exp(-x))^2\right)$$
Now you should be able to finish it off.

**EDIT**
$$\sinh(a+b) = \sinh(a) \cos(b) + \sinh(b) \cosh(a)$$ This is similar to the formula $$\sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) + \sin(b) \cos(a)$$
In your problem, take $a=b=x$.

Comment: I don't understand, how does this apply to my problem?

Comment: I need to figure out this problem without using exp. I'm basically filling in the ? in WebAssign.

Comment: ok so $\sinh 2x = \sinh (x + x)$ and $\sinh x \cosh x + \cosh x \sinh x$, what happens in the end?

Comment: @dsta Yes. You can then expand to get what you want.

Comment: so, where do I go from there?

Comment: @dsta Just add the two terms. Since both terms are the same terms you get $2 \sinh(x) \cosh(x)$